# How to open new tab or new browser window in IE broswer by clicking h:commandButton without JavaScript?

Tags: jsf

In my application I need  to open new tab or browser window in internet explorer by clicking  `<h:commandButton>` without using JavaScript code. How can I do this?

After I searched details from some blogs I tried the following code. It's working fine in  Firefox browser, but not in IE browser. I need it for IE browser without using JavaScript code.

```
<h:form target="_blank">
    <h:commandButton value="" action="" />
</h:form>
```